# How to circumvent Class.forName() method

Tags: java, reflection

I need to parse XML file and create bunch of objects from `ArrayList` with reflection.

I achieved this with `Class.forName()`.

Here is my code:

```
public ArrayList<Sweets> parse(String fileName) throws Exception {

    File file = new File(fileName);
    Document doc = builder.parse(file);

    ArrayList<Sweets> items = new ArrayList<Sweets>();
    int itemCount = Integer.parseInt(path
            .evaluate("count(/gift/item)", doc));

    for (int i = 1; i <= itemCount; i++) {

        double sugar = Double.parseDouble(path.evaluate("/gift/item[" + i + "]/@sugar", doc));
        String name = path.evaluate("/gift/item[" + i + "]/name", doc);
        double weight = Double.parseDouble(path.evaluate("/gift/item[" + i
                + "]/weight", doc));

        Class cl = Class.forName("com.epam.lab.model.chocolate." + name);
        items.add((Sweets) cl.getConstructor(double.class, double.class)
                .newInstance(sugar, weight));
    }

    return items;
}
```

It works but at this line:

```
Class cl = Class.forName("com.epam.lab.model.chocolate." + name);
```

But some disadvantage is that this method need to have full name of class include packages.

It takes exactly from distinct package. But I need to take other classes from other location. Limitation of `forName()` doesn't let me do this.

**How to circumvent `Class.forName()` constraints?**

Comment: "rescission"? Did you mean... "reflection"?

Comment: You can try a number of packages, or you can use https://code.google.com/p/reflections/ which indexes and searches for classes for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a nice alternative to reading and parsing XML into Java objects: JAXB with annotations.

Reading by:

```
MyDoc doc = load(MyDoc.class, "/mydoc.xml");

private <T> T load(Class<T> klazz, String xmlResource) {
    try {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(klazz);
        return klazz.cast(jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller()
                .unmarshal(getClass().getResourceAsStream(xmlResource)));
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,
                "Cannot read resource " + xmlResource, e);
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
}

@XmlRootElement(name="document")
public class MyDoc {

    @XmlElement(name="sweetsList")
    public List<Sweets> sweets= new ArrayList<>();
}

<document>
    <sweetsList>
        ...
    </sweetsList>
</document>
```

And same annotations with `@XmlElement` and `@XmlAttribute` for the other classes.

Comment: can you recommend nice jaxb tutorial?

Comment: JAXB over time has developed into something easy. So it is hard for me to give pointers. Before annotations there was .xsd, schemas in XML, to define the java structure. I found that more error prone than annotations. Maybe an IDE might give support, NetBeans IDE, IntelliJ IDEA, eclipse+plugin. Good luck in your research.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it's not possible - to instantiate you need to provide fully qualified name of the class.

But maybe you can provide more information in parsed xml - e.g. part of the package name which differs between types of sweets?

```
String name = path.evaluate("/gift/item[" + i + "]/name", doc);
String type = path.evaluate("/gift/item[" + i + "]/type", doc);
double weight = Double.parseDouble(path.evaluate("/gift/item[" + i + "]/weight", doc));
Class cl = Class.forName("com.epam.lab.model" + type + "." + name);
```

Or if XML format is sealed, then maybe you can create a mapping between particular sweets names and packages of classess which represent them?